# In Weka when classifying test data with a model, getting the Illegal options exception

Tags: weka

When running a weka classifier on new test data, with a model created earlier, I'm getting a vague `illegal options` exception,

```
java -cp ~/weka/weka.jar weka.classifiers.meta.AdaBoostM1    \
> -T dataset.2015-06-16T192725.test.arff  \
> -l dataset.2015-06-16T192725.train.model 

Weka exception: Illegal options:   

General options:

-h or -help
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that for this command, and probably many others, the order of the arguments in Weka matters.

When I changed the command to the below, the result was good,

```
java -cp ~/weka/weka.jar weka.classifiers.meta.AdaBoostM1    \
> -l dataset.2015-06-16T192725.train.model \
> -T dataset.2015-06-16T192725.test.arff
```